# SQL Server stored procedure slows every execution

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I've got a stored procedure which does many selects and updates with some cursors.

When I execute the procedure the first time, it takes about 30 seconds. Second execution takes about 1 minute. Third about 2 minutes.

Every execution slows the procedure. Now it takes about 10 minutes.

What is going wrong?

Variables:

```
declare @StatistikStatus nvarchar(100)
declare @SQL as nvarchar(MAX)
declare @Datum  as nvarchar(50) --Datum im nvarchar Format
declare @Datumdatetime datetime --Datum im datetime Format
declare @tickethistorieID as uniqueidentifier
declare @id int --ID der Terminauswertung. Wird bei Einträgen benötigt, die pro Ticket mehrere Termine vereinbart haben.
declare @nextTermin datetime --Wird bei Einträgen benötigt, die pro Ticket mehrere Termine vereinbart haben.
declare @status nvarchar(100)
declare @statusdiff as nvarchar(100)
declare @vorStatus as nvarchar(100)
declare @lastid as int
declare @tickethistoriemerker nvarchar(40)
declare @statistikstatusmerker nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @TicketID uniqueidentifier
```

Sample cursor:

```
DECLARE C_TicketHistorie CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  
        dbo.TicketHistorie.TicketID,dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum,dbo.tickethistorie.tickethistorieid
    FROM 
        dbo.TicketHistorie INNER JOIN
        dbo.Status ON dbo.TicketHistorie.NeueStatusID = dbo.Status.StatusID
        INNER JOIN dbo.StatuszuStatistikStatus as s on s.status_ID = dbo.Status.statusid
        INNER JOIN dbo.StatistikStatus as ss on s.bewertung_id = ss.id
    WHERE     
    ss.id = 5 AND -- 5 = HNR Terminbestätigung
        (dbo.Status.Name = N'Termin vereinbart') 
     AND ((YEAR(dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum) >= 2011 and day(dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum) >= 27 and month(dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum) >= 12)or YEAR(dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum) >= 2012)

    ORDER BY TicketID,Datum asc
OPEN C_TicketHistorie;

FETCH NEXT FROM C_TicketHistorie into @TicketID,@Datumdatetime,@TickethistorieID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--some inserts etc.
FETCH NEXT FROM C_TicketHistorie into @TicketID,@Datumdatetime,@TickethistorieID
END
CLOSE C_TicketHistorie
DEALLOCATE C_TicketHistorie
```

I've got 4 cursors. 
And some dynamix SQL like this

```
SET @SQL ='UPDATE Statistik.dbo.terminauswertungab27122011 SET ['
                SET @SQL =@SQL + @StatistikStatus+']='''
                SET @SQL =@SQL + cast(@TicketHistorieID as NVARCHAR(36))+''''
                SET @SQL =@SQL + ' WHERE ID = ' + cast(@ID as nvarchar) +' and ['+@StatistikStatus+'] IS NULL' 
                EXEC (@SQL)
```

I call the procedure using SSMS.

at the beginning of the stp i delete the table where the inserts goes into. Then iam doing the Inserts. the table rows are the same every execution

Comment: Does this happen when you call the stored procedure using [SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx)? or only when you call it from code? We need more details about the proc and how you're using it.

Comment: You would need to provide more details, nobody can do more than guess with that little.

Comment: I guess the most probable reason is that you are processing more data with every execution - are you copying/moving data to tables that show (unintended) growth? May it's not your procedure executing so slow but your database busy allocating more space.

Comment: iam using SSMS

at the beginning of the stp i delete the table where the inserts goes into. Then iam doing the Inserts. the table rows are the same every execution

Comment: Are you deleting from the table or dropping the whole table? What are your settings for database and log growth? Your problem still sounds like your db is busy allocation (log)space. Executing the same procedures with the same source data couldn't result in exponentially execution time.

Comment: I just read the part about FOUR cursors. Wow. There is a lot to be said about being able to program with set-based queries in mind. I hate to sound like Celko, and while there is certainly a place for the occasional cursor, they are typically the default mindset of folks who think we are in the 70s working with tape or other physical formats...

Comment: I am deleting the whole table, then I create it again and then I fill it. I am doing this because of dynamically columns. How can I get database and log growth? How can i prevent that db is busy allocating logspace?

Comment: Post your whole procedure and then someone might be able to see what's wrong, it could be just one cursor is incorrectly growing or some factor that you don't expect.

Answer (score 2):

First off, change your cursor declaration to a more efficient cursor:

```
DECLARE C_TicketHistorie CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR
```

Next, are you sure that you need a cursor for these operations? It seems that your update, for example, could be accomplished as a single set-based operation instead of a cursor and dynamic SQL, especially if you know the set of column names that could be indicated by @StatistikStatus (where is this determined, by the way?). Here is how you could generate a set-based dynamic SQL update in one swoop instead of a cursor:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

WITH x AS
(
    SELECT  
        -- why only use aliases for the tables you don't reference often?
        th.TicketID, th.Datum, th.tickethistorieid
    FROM 
        dbo.TicketHistorie AS th
        INNER JOIN dbo.Status AS st
          ON th.NeueStatusID = st.StatusID
        INNER JOIN dbo.StatuszuStatistikStatus as s 
          on s.status_ID = st.statusid
        INNER JOIN dbo.StatistikStatus as ss 
          on s.bewertung_id = ss.id
    WHERE     
      ss.id = 5 -- 5 = HNR Terminbestätigung 
      AND st.Name = N'Termin vereinbart'
     -- be smarter about date range queries!
      AND dbo.TicketHistorie.Datum >= '2011127'
)
SELECT @sql += N'UPDATE Statistik.dbo.terminauswertungab27122011 SET ['
       + @StatistikStatus+']='''
       + cast(@TicketHistorieID as NVARCHAR(36))+''''
       + ' WHERE ID = ' + cast(@ID as nvarchar) + ' -- nvarchar(WHAT)?
       and ['+@StatistikStatus+'] IS NULL;';
```

Probably a lot more optimization possible here, but as the comments suggest, tough to do without more info.

Comment: I think it's not the right way to find optimizations. The main question is why is takes longer and longer every excecution

Comment: @MariusKrämer - Impossible for us to say. You would need to add some profiling code to see what specific things are taking longer then ask a much more specific question.